# Can't connect to Mysql from asp.net api

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, wamp

I have some hard time to connect to mySQL server... Everytime, I tried to connect, I got a "Internal connection fatal error" message. 
Here is some parts of my code : 
Startup.cs :

```
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyAppContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")));  

    services.AddControllers();
}
```

appsettings.json :

```
"ConnectionStrings": 
  {
    "MyConnectionString" : "server=localhost,3306;database=myDB;user=root;password="
  }
```

My csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

For the ConnectionStrings part, I tried this :

```
"ConnectionStrings": 
  {
    "MyConnectionString" : "server=localhost;database=myDB;user=root;password="
  }
```

But this time, I got this message : "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"
For you information, my sqlserver is running with WAMP.
I hope I was clear, don't hesitate if you more informations or mode pieces of code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are using Mysql OR SQLServer? Your code seems to written for SQL server but you mention Mysql in the title.

Answer (score 2):

I think you must download MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore instead of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.

Comment: are you in dotnet core?

Comment: Yes, i'm in .net core

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySql driver to connect MySql server. For EF Core you must download this [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql).

In version .Net 3.1, you can use code below after download the Pomelo Nuget package;

```
        services.AddDbContext<MyAppContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseMySql(configuration.GetConnectionString("MySqlConnection"));

        });
```

In version .Net 5;

```
        string connectionString =configuration.GetConnectionString("MySqlConnection")
        services.AddDbContext<MyAppContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseMySql(connectionString,
                         ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)));

        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to work now but I have another issue... I tried to do `dotnet ef migrations remove` but i have this error now :  **Method 'Create' in type 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.MySqlSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory' from assembly 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql, Version=3.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2cc498582444921b' does not have an implementation.**

Comment: I think this related to package version incompatibility. Your EF Core version and Pomelo version should be compatible. But I'm not sure about that. Take a look and notify me :)

Comment: My verison of EF is 5.0.3

Comment: So, you can use Pomelo 5.0.0-alpha.1 or Pomelo 5.0.0-alpha.2  version. Version 3.2.4.0 compatible with .net core 3.x

Comment: Okay, I did but I have another issue... Sorry I'm pretty new at  it. Now i have **error cs1503 argument 2 cannot convert from 'string' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion'**. I tried this `opt.UseMySql(configuration.GetConnectionString("MySqlConnection"),
                         new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 21)));` but it's not working

Comment: Recreate your migrations and try again.

Comment: Okay I gonna try.. But i had this error when I did a `dotnet build`

Comment: Okey, i edited server version part in my answer again please take a look.

Comment: Please mark as accepted answer if this answer helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

dotnet core: nuget - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer then you will be good. Remove all other entity frame Packages from your project

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddControllersWithViews();

```
        var connectionString =Configuration.GetConnectionString("MYDB_DbCoreConnectionString");
         services.AddDbContext<MYDContext>(options1 => options1.UseSqlServer(connectionString)) ;

        var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

        // configure jwt authentication
        var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });

        // configure DI for application services
        services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
        

}
```